# Flutter Camera takePicture not working on Android 12

Tags: flutter, dart, android-camera

I had a code that was working ok but after Android-12 it started to freeze. It uses "camera: ^0.10.5" dependency. It gets no error also no results, just frozen.

Here is the code. It freezes on the takePicture() async call.

```
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  TakePictureScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final CameraDescription camera = getIt<CameraDescription>();

  @override
  TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
}

class TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  late CameraController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;
  
  void _initializeCameraController() {
    _controller = CameraController(
      widget.camera,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
    );

    initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }
  
  void initializeCameraController() {
    _controller = CameraController(
      widget.camera,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
    );

    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initializeCameraController();
  }
  
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (!_controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return;
    }

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      _controller.dispose();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      _initializeCameraController();
    }
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Images')),
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
            return CameraPreview(_controller);
          } else {
            // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      // when you click floatingActionButton it takes picture
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            await _initializeControllerFuture;

            //final image = await _controller.takePicture();
            final XFile image = await _controller.takePicture();
            //image.saveTo("path");

            // after taking picture, send it to custom preview screen
            context.push(
              Routes.checkinPreview,
              arguments: ScreenArguments({
                "takenPicture": image.path
              }),
            );
          } on CameraException catch (e) {
            context.snackbar(e.description ?? "");
            context.snackbar(takePictureError);
          } on Exception catch (e) {
            context.snackbar(takePictureError);
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

I tried to upgrade the Flutter version and the whole dependencies. After that, I reviewed the camera dependency playbook and applied the new exampled. Still no results.

This is the depenency: https://pub.dev/packages/camera

Comment: maybe this helps : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126125

Comment: I read the whole content and redirected links as well. But no successful result.

Comment: it appears that issue is related to package itself and they are working on it